# How can i use the google storage api to make the files publicly shared?

Tags: java, permissions, google-cloud-storage

I have a java projet hosted on GCE.

I'm using `google-api-services-storage`

to create a folder on G-storage and upload some files there.

How can i use the google storage api to make the files publicly shared?

I don't see the java documentation for that.

here is my try:

```
    Storage gsClient;
    StorageFileId gcsFileId = fileIdCreator.createFromUri(gcsFileURI);
    List<ObjectAccessControl> acl = new ArrayList<>();
    //acl.add(new ObjectAccessControl().setRole(""));
    //acl.add(Acl.of(Acl.User.ofAllUsers(), Acl.Role.READER));
    acl.add(new ObjectAccessControl().setRole("READER").setProjectTeam(new ObjectAccessControl.ProjectTeam().setTeam("viewers")));
    StorageObject object = new StorageObject().setName(gcsFileId.getObjectId()).setAcl(acl);
    InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent("application/octet-stream", inputStream);
    Storage.Objects.Insert insertRequest = gsClient.objects().insert(gcsFileId.getBucket(), object, mediaContent);

    insertRequest.getMediaHttpUploader().setDirectUploadEnabled(true);

    insertRequest.execute();
```

I saw this [php documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/public_access)

and this [json documantation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objectAccessControls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"projectTeam" is a read-only property. You instead need to construct an "entity", like so:

```
    acl.add(new ObjectAccessControl().setRole("READER").setEntity("allUsers"));
```

Comment: thanks, and how would i set this acl to files which are already on the cloud?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749778/how-to-use-java-to-set-acl-to-all-files-under-google-storage-folder